# Working with git on two computer (with github)

Tags: git, github, cherry-pick

I'have a python project and I decide today put it on github.
I'm newbie with that. I see several tutorial. All work fine exept a thing I want to do:

I'm coding on my laptop in the day and on my computer I continue the work when I come back home.For now I create a repo on the laptop and I push it on my github. When I come back home on my computer I did a clone of the repo to continue working on the code. But when I push it on github again , all work fine exept I don't know how to "download" it on my laptop again to continue working in the next day.

The only things I find is to make a "cherry pick". I don't know if it's correct and how to process in this situation.

Comment: I've found this book to be very useful: http://progit.org/book/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you've cloned, `git pull` will update your local copy with the latest from the repository it was cloned from.  See the [`git pull` section](http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#getting-updates-With-git-pull) of the manual for more information.

**Update for git gui:**
I encourage you to learn bash and the command-line interface for git, apart from being incredibly useful, it's easier to find support for them.

Looking at the "Pulling from a Remote Server" section of the git gui [tour](http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/tour.html), it appears that pulling involves adding a remote (perhaps already done) and then selecting *Remote* -> *fetch from* -> *repository name*.

Comment: okay thank.Did you know what is the fonction of "git pull" in gitgui ? I not feel confortable with git bash commandline.

Comment: I think `remote>fetch from` has the same functionality as a pull

Comment: Okay ... with some keys you give to me with your answer , I find that the best way to do it is to fetch , check the change , and merge after. It's apparently why it's not available in gitgui. Because pull is a faster way to do it and a kind of "power-user" feature if I understand (my english is not soo good as you can see). Where I find it : http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/No-quot-pull-quot-in-git-gui-td1121058.html

Comment: In your case, `git pull` would be more convenient than `git fetch` + `git merge` (unless you want to double-check all your work), but yes, they're essentially equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

To put it on github from any computer use `push` to get it from github to any computer use `pull`